# Tengo problemas para deserializar un dato booleano

Tags: c#, json, postman, .net-core

Presento mi caso:

Tengo un archivo JSON con información X con este campo (que es con lo que estoy teniendo problemas);

```
{
    "isUrgent": true,
}
```

En VS Professional con c# y .net Core tengo el siguiente código:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RegisterObject
{
    [JsonProperty("isUrgent", Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool IsUrgent { get; set; }
}
```

A través de Postman, envío mi JSON a la solución VS Proffesional.

```
{
    "isUrgent": 100
}
```

Envío el JSON con esta variable con un valor numérico para ver qué sucede (estamos probando) y el sistema lo convierte a Boolean, específicamente al valor true, dándolo el sistema como válido.

Espero que puedas ayudarme :) Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Hola! ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: La pregunta sería por qué está convirtiendo un entero a booleano, pero ya está resuelto es tema de la librería de Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, la necesitamos así que no podemos hacer más aquí :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente la librería Newtonsoft usa [Convert.ToBoolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean?view=net-6.0) para convertir. Esta función ante un int devuelve false si es 0 y true en cualquier otro caso

```
var t1= Convert.ToBoolean(100); //true
var t2= Convert.ToBoolean(1); //true
var t3= Convert.ToBoolean(12); //true
var t4= Convert.ToBoolean(0); //false
```

Recomiendo usar System.Text.Json, que es la Liberia que viene con .net. Usando esta librería tienes que da false como uno esperaría

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si se deja como nulleable entrega null, que es aún más correcto

```
public bool? IsUrgent { get; set; }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias pero al ser cosas de empresa por ahora no hay opción para cambiarlo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Creo que ya podemos cerrar el post :)